# Mustache template string inside render as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mustache

I am using Mustache to render templates.

I have this json object:

```
  {
    title: "Foo bar", 
    content: "<p> Html here </p>", 
    footer: "footer content here"
  }
```

I have a Mustache template like:

```
  <div id="box">
    <div id="title"> {{title}} </div> 
    <div id="content"> {{content}} </div> 
    <div id="footer"> {{footer}} </div> 
  </div>
```

My problem is that the html within the variable content is not getting rendered but instead is just getting printed to the screen.

I see (in non-view source window): `<p> Html here </p>`, where I would only want to see that if I viewed the page source.

How can I fix such that when I pass in a string to a mustache template the HTML inside gets rendered? I am calling mustache.render(templates.all,data); as my call to mustache.

Comment: Would be great if you could accept the answer to mark the question as solved.

Comment: Agreed.........

Answer (score 168):

From the [Mustache documentation](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html):

> All variables are HTML escaped by default. If you want to return
>   unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: {{{name}}}.

So you just have to use eg.`{{{content}}}` in your template:

```
  <div id="box">
    <div id="title"> {{title}} </div> 
    <div id="content"> {{{content}}} </div> 
    <div id="footer"> {{footer}} </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: I know that this is an old post, but I need to solve this but with the difference that I want to assign {{{content}}} to a javascript variable in order to use in oder javascript files inside of my site.

Comment: If you want to get the `content` as a variable, you would do that in the code that is calling the template render. You can't extract the data out of a rendered template. (A hack-ish way, would be to render the template, then extract it out of the DOM using `documents.querySelector(...).textContent`)

Comment: @cmarrero01 then you can put a partial {{> cnt}} to template and pass variable object `{"cnt": content}` as third parameter to `render` function.
Like here http://jsfiddle.net/EYDfP/169/

Comment: {{{}}} is not working for me